# Is it possible to simplify this nested GCD?

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, iterated-function-system

Is it possible to simplify this nested GCD?

> $$\gcd\bigg(\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2)),\frac{m^2}{\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))}\bigg)$$

Here, $\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))>1$ and $\sigma(m^2)$ is the sum of divisors of $m^2$.

I tried using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolynomialGCD%5BPolynomialGCD%5Bm%5E2,%20DivisorSigma%5B1,%20m%5E2%5D%5D,%20(m%5E2%2F(PolynomialGCD%5Bm%5E2,%20DivisorSigma%5B1,%20m%5E2%5D%5D))%5D), but it appears to evaluate the GCD *erroneously* to
$$\gcd\bigg(\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2)),\frac{m^2}{\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))}\bigg) = 1.$$

This is because I know from a published result that the following must hold for the problem that I am considering:
$$\gcd\bigg(\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2)),\frac{m^2}{\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))}\bigg) > 1.$$

**Updated (March 2 2019)**

I tried to evaluate the simpler expression
$$\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))$$
using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolynomialGCD%5Bm%5E2,%20DivisorSigma%5B1,%20m%5E2%5D%5D), and obtained
$$\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2)) = 1,$$
which I know to be false.  Hence, it appears that my problem cannot be solved using WolframAlpha alone.

I have therefore removed the **wolfram-alpha** and **computer-algebra-systems** tags.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the nested GCD in question can be simplified using GCD associativity as follows?
$$\gcd\bigg(\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2)),\frac{m^2}{\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))}\bigg) = \gcd\bigg(\sigma(m^2),\gcd\left(m^2,\frac{m^2}{\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))}\right)\bigg) = \gcd\bigg(\sigma(m^2),\frac{m^2}{\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))}\bigg)?$$

Comment: The $\gcd$ isn't greater than one, and I believe WolframAlpha is not wrong, I tested for $m=1,\; 2,\;3,\;\cdots,\;7$ and both WolframAlpha results were right, of course this isn't a proof, but at least gives a counter example to your claim that the $\gcd$ is greater than $1$

Comment: @BrunoAndrades:  Thank you for your comment.

I used [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org) and found the following examples for $\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))>1$ for $m < 100$:

$$14, 21, 39, 42, 57, 63, 70, 77, 78, 84, 93, 98, 99$$

Comment: Well that was unexpected, I guess neither WolframAlpha or the OP is right

Comment: @BrunoAndrades:  I used the following GP code in Sage Cell Server to produce the above examples:  for (x=1, 100,if(gcd(x^2,sigma(x^2))>1,print(x))).

Comment: I also used the following Mathematica code to double-check the exact same results by Sage Cell Server:  Select[Range[10^2], GCD[#^2, DivisorSigma[1, #^2]] > 1 &]

Comment: @BrunoAndrades:  Well, actually, what makes the computations more difficult is the fact that it is known that $m > {10}^{375}$, for the particular problem that I am considering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt:

By GCD associativity,
$$\gcd\bigg(\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2)),\frac{m^2}{\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))}\bigg)=\gcd\bigg(\sigma(m^2),\gcd\left(m^2,\frac{m^2}{\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))}\right)\bigg).$$

Next, since
$$\frac{m^2}{\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))} \mid m^2,$$
then
$$\gcd\left(m^2,\frac{m^2}{\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))}\right)=\frac{m^2}{\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))},$$
so that we obtain
$$\gcd\bigg(\sigma(m^2),\gcd\left(m^2,\frac{m^2}{\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))}\right)\bigg)=\gcd\bigg(\sigma(m^2),\frac{m^2}{\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))}\bigg).$$

Using the formula $\gcd(na,nb)=n\gcd(a,b)$, we get
$$\gcd\bigg(\sigma(m^2),\frac{m^2}{\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))}\bigg)=\frac{\gcd\bigg(\sigma(m^2)\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2)),m^2\bigg)}{\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))}=\frac{\gcd\bigg(\gcd(m^2 \sigma(m^2),(\sigma(m^2))^2),m^2\bigg)}{\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))}.$$

Again, by GCD associativity, we obtain
$$\frac{\gcd\bigg(\gcd\left(m^2 \sigma(m^2),(\sigma(m^2))^2\right),m^2\bigg)}{\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))}=\frac{\gcd\bigg(\gcd(m^2 \sigma(m^2),m^2),(\sigma(m^2))^2\bigg)}{\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))}.$$

Now, since
$$m^2 \mid m^2 \sigma(m^2)$$
we get
$$\gcd(m^2 \sigma(m^2),m^2) = m^2$$
so that we finally have
$$\frac{\gcd\bigg(\gcd(m^2 \sigma(m^2),m^2),(\sigma(m^2))^2\bigg)}{\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))} = \frac{\gcd\bigg(m^2, (\sigma(m^2))^2\bigg)}{\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))} = \frac{\bigg(\gcd(m,\sigma(m^2))\bigg)^2}{\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))}.$$