# If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then its index at the prime $q$ is not a square.

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Let $N=q^k n^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) with special prime $q$.  (That is, $q$ satisfies $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.)

The index $i(q)$ of $N$ at the prime $q$ is then equal to
$$i(q):=\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2}=\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)}=\frac{s(n^2)}{D(q^k)/2}=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)),$$
where $D(x):=2x-\sigma(x)$ is the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) and $s(x):=\sigma(x)-x$ is the [sum of aliquot divisors](http://oeis.org/A001065) of $x \in \mathbb{N}$.

In this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3131818), it is shown that

> $$\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=\gcd\bigg(i(q),\frac{n^2}{i(q)}\bigg).$$

Furthermore, in this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3132285), taking $m=n$ and noting that $i(q)=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$, essentially it has been proven that
$$\gcd\bigg(\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)),\frac{n^2}{\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))}\bigg)=\frac{\bigg(\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))\bigg)^2}{\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))},$$
so that $$G := \gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)) \text{ is a square} \iff i(q) = \gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)) \text{ is a square.}$$

Note that
$$G = \gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)) = \gcd\bigg(\sigma(q^k)/2,\sigma(n^2)\bigg)$$
as $\sigma(n^2)$ is odd.

I now wish to prove the following proposition:

**PROPOSITION** If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then its index at the prime $q$ is not a square.

*Proof* Assume to the contrary that 
$$i(q) = \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} = \frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2}$$
is a square.

It follows that $\sigma(q^k)/2$ and
$$G = \gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)) = \gcd\bigg(\sigma(q^k)/2,\sigma(n^2)\bigg)$$
are both squares.  Hence, $\sigma(n^2)$ is also a square, by the GCD property $$\gcd(x^2, y^2) = \bigg(\gcd(x,y)\bigg)^2.$$

But $i(q) = \sigma(n^2)/q^k$ and $\sigma(n^2)$ are both squares would imply that $q^k$ is a square, which clearly contradicts $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  (In fact, $i(q)$ is a square implies $k=1$ by a result of Broughan, Delbourgo, and Zhou ([Improving the Chen and Chen Result for Odd Perfect Numbers](http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/INTEGERS/papers/n39/n39.pdf)).)

**QED**

**Question**

> Is this proof logically sound/correct?

Comment: It seems to me that you are claiming that $\sigma(n^2)$ is a square without any proof. That $\sigma(n^2)$ is a square does not follow from $\gcd(x^2, y^2) = (\gcd(x,y))^2$. What you have to prove is that if $\gcd(a^2,b)=c^2$, then $b$ is a square. However, this is not true in general. A counterexample is $(a,b,c)=(6,27,3)$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @mathlove!  I think that qualifies as a response to my original inquiry.  I invite you to write that out as an answer, so that I may be able to accept it.

Comment: I converted my comment into an answer.

Comment: Gladly accepting your answer now, @mathlove!  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are claiming that $\sigma(n^2)$ is a square without any proof.

That $\sigma(n^2)$ is a square does not follow from $$\gcd(x^2,y^2)=\bigg(\gcd(x,y)\bigg)^2$$

What you have to prove is that if $\gcd(a^2,b)=c^2$, then $b$ is a square.

However, this is not true in general. A counterexample is $(a,b,c)=(6,27,3)$.